# CMake error when creating project in CLion

Tags: windows, c, mingw, cmake

I recently uninstalled Cygwin and switched to using MinGW as my toolchain. I installed the required packages; I triple checked to make sure that mingw32-make, mingw32-gcc and mingw32-gcc-g++ are all installed. This is what CLion says, however, when it tries to detect:

[image]

Whenever I try to make a new project, I get multiple CMake errors, like `file STRINGS file
  "C:/Users/me/CLionProjects/project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.9.4/CompilerIdC/a.exe"
  cannot be read.` I looked for the file, and it doesn't exist. What does this mean? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into this issue today, seems to be a recent windows update. What worked for me was adding "cmake.exe" as a process exclusion in the Windows Defender Security Center.

Comment: Cmake.exe? Do you mean mingw32-make.exe?

Comment: Adding cmake.exe fixed the error in your question for me. I still get a threat detection warning from windows when trying to build the target though. Also my built exe's don't have an entry point but I am not on my normal dev machine right now, could be a configuration issue on my end. Turning off all real time protection didn't fix this for me either.